# Svelte: Array mutation and re-assignment not triggering re-render in #each block

Tags: svelte, svelte-3, svelte-component

[image: Svelte App REPL]

I don't know why this isn't updating. I'm relatively new to Svelte but I know about force updating objects arrays with the thing = thing method.

Still, I'm not sure why this doesn't re-render whatsoever? I had this as a Matrix first of all and I thought maybe there was some nestedness that was breaking it but now this is literally just a flat array. It's updating on the matrix on click but not triggering re-render.

```
<script>
    import Nested from './Nested.svelte';
    let matrix = new Array(9).fill(null)
    let turn = 0
    
    let handleChange = (index) => {
        if (matrix[index] != null) return
        let newColor = turn % 2 == 0 ? 'red' : 'blue'
        matrix[index]= newColor
        turn++
        matrix = matrix
    }
</script>
    {#each matrix as team, index}
        <Nested team={team} index={index} click={handleChange}/>
        {#if (index==2 || index==5)}
            <br />
        {/if}
    {/each}
```

Nested Component:

```
<script>
    export let index;
    export let click;
    export let team;
    
    let color = 'white';
    if (team) color = team;
</script>

<style>
    div {
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        border: 1px solid black;
        display: inline-block;
        margin: 0;
    }
</style>

<div style="background-color: {color}" on:click={(e)=>click(index)}>
    {color}
</div>
```

Comment: Looks like changing the if statement to a reactive statement in your Nested component fixes it `$: if (team) color = team;`  Here's a REPL https://svelte.dev/repl/b3503816416240e7a66859d5fd95c00c?version=3.38.3

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When working with Svelte, an important thing to keep in mind is that the code in the `script` block is only execution when the component is created.

In your case, this means that the line `if (team) color = team;` only runs *once* (at instantiation) and never again afterwards.

If you want something to be re-executed, you have to declare it reactive using `$:`

For you that would become

```js
$: if (team) color = team
```

This will be re-executed whenever any of the variables used (team and color) changes.

Note that you can also simply mark a variable to be reactive (Svelte injects the *let* for you)

```js
export let index;
export let click;
export let team;
    
$: color = team ?? 'white'
```